# 403 when trying to access googleapis.com from within docker container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, orchestration

I am trying to deploy a small python based webapp that uses the `google.oauth2` package for authentication. The webapp runs in a container that uses `python:3.10` as its base. The authentication works as expected when running locally on the computer directly and in a container. If I try to deploy the webapp on the server, it can't connect to google for authentication.

After some debugging I found out that google reacts with a `403 Forbidden` to every request sent from within the container to its services. I can connect from the server directly though.

I tested with `curl`:

- On the server without container:

  - curl https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

    - cert JSON results as expected
- On the server in the container

  - curl https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

    - 403 forbidden
  - curl https://google.com

    - 403 forbidden
  - curl https://stackoverflow.com

    - website HTML as expected
- locally in the container

  - curl https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs

    - cert JSON results as expected

My (abbreviated) dockerfile is

```
FROM python:3.10

<Installing libraries and setting up some creds>


#RUN
WORKDIR /code
CMD ["uvicorn", "user_api.api.server:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

My (abbreviated) compose file is:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  user_api:
    image: user_api:latest
    ports:
      - "8100:80"
    env_file:
      - /home/user/.env
```

The server is hosted on Hetzner Cloud and has a static IPv4.

I have tried accessing multiple websites from within the container. All google owned domains I have tries respond with a 403, all other websites I have tested with seem to work.

I am also able to ping google.com and googleapis.com.

I have done the same tests on the server directly, on my local computer and inside of the container running on my local computer. The only place where it doesn't work is inside the container, on the server.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I think it is related to the Hetzner Cloud. It was working for me a few weeks ago, so something might have changed on their end.
-Have you been able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to Hetzner servers being blocked by google.
The reason why it only happens in the docker and maybe works in the server itself is that maybe only the ipv4 is blocked and your ipv6 works.
If the docker is then only configured for ipv4 it only fails on it.

You can test it with "curl --ipv4 www.google.com" or "curl --ipv6 www.google.com". I had servers/ip addresses that only worked on ipv4, only with ipv6 and didn't work on both.

Comment: we have the same problem.
is there anything we can do to get unblocked?
will google react to whitelisting request? if so, how to do it? this is pretty messed up!
our k8s workloads using google-cloud-datastore library fail with 403

Comment: I haven't tried to contact google about it but i know the issue is known by the hetzner team and actively being worked on. The main problem is misuse of the hetzner instances.
My solution was to reserve a bunch of primary ips that don't have the issue and then assign those to the servers. I have got a script i can share that basically boots a server, adds the ip, tests it and deletes it if blocked. There is a max of primary ips to reserve though + cost.